# how to flutter convert maps to String

Tags: list, sqlite, dictionary, flutter

hello i get data in sqlite
code :

```
getuserIDPW(String email) async{
    final db = await database;
    var res = await db.query("person",columns: ['email', 'password'] ,where: "email = ?", whereArgs: [email]);
    return res.isNotEmpty? res : Null;
  }
```

code :

```
var useridpw = await DBHelper().getuserIDPW(_email);
        print(useridpw);
```

That's how I got the result of `[{email: kmail, password: 123123}]`

But i want String like this : `var tmpEmail = 'kmail';`

How to get String in map ?

I'd be grateful if someone would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can get you email by doing this :

first u have a list so u should map it

```
var email ; 
useridpw.map((e) {
email = e['email'];
}).toList()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below code if you want to get specific String :-

```
Future<String> getuserIDPW(String email) async{
      final db = await database;
      var res = await db.query("person",columns: ['email', 'password'] ,where: "email = ?", whereArgs: [email]);
      return res.isNotEmpty? res[0][yourKey like 'email' OR 'password'] : Null;
    }
```